# How to insert image in magento cms editor

Tags: image, magento, insert, editor

i am trying to insert images using editor in magento from the admin panel. images are uploading without issue but after the upload i am clicking on insert image. but the path is not coming into the popup src url. so i am unable to place image into editor.

anybody help me please.

thanks,
murali.

Comment: Probably a better fit for http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

1. Upload the image like you said
2. Select the proper folder in the left column and click the image in the right column.
3. Press Insert Image in the upper right corner.
4. See code like : `<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/filename.jpg"}}" alt="" />` appear in the text-area

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you can't add an image like you're supposed to.
This problem is related to Firefox, at least in my case this is.

If you select an image in Chrome or in IE it works.
In Firefox it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your images in `http://magento.com/images` directory.
2. Click on Show/Hide Editor.
3. Change/edit the `src` tag eg `src="/images/banner1.jpg"`.

Answer (score 0):

From what you're describing, once you see the uploaded image in the Image Manager...double-click the image and it will go into your editor with a custom URL

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to do it:

```
<img src="{{skin url='images/YOUR-IMAGE.jpg'}}" />
```